# Is there a way of making discord embeds better?

Tags: javascript, bots, embed, discord, discord.js

I'm developing my own discord bot, my issues are the embeds, are there some trick or modules in node.js that can help me beautify those?

The only thing I had to try were the default embeds, which to be fair I don't like much

```js
else if (message.content.startsWith(`${ prefix }queue`)) {
    if (!serverQueue){
        message.channel.send('Nothing playing');
        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 13702935,
                description: `**Song Queue**
                ${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `**-**${song.title}`).join("\n")}
                **Now Playing:** ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}
                `
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor('Song Queue',message.guild.iconURL) //<- optional
.addField(`Song Queue`,`${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `**-**${song.title}`).join("\n")}`,true)
.addField(`Now Playing`,`${serverQueue.songs[0].title}`,true)
.setTimestamp()
.setColor("#hexcode")
.setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.avatarURL)
message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [this page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembed-constructor) 
it shows you some more possible fields

You can also take a look at one of my bot's embeds.

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Add Jerseyetr')
    .setURL('xxxxxx')
    .setAuthor('Midnight Bot', 'image.png', 'https://xxxxxxxx.com')
    .setDescription('')
    .setThumbnail(imageFromGoogle.png')
    .addField('How to Gain Access to the Server', '1. Go to the Rules Section and read the rules \n2. Add XXXX on Steam. Link above \n3. Download and install our mods. Check the #information Channel for info')
    .addBlankField()
    .addField('Mods download:', 'https://xxxxxxxxx', true)
    .addField('how to install mods', 'https://xxxxxxx', true)
    .addField('Vote for our Server', 'https://xxxxx', true)
    .setImage('')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Updated 5/20', 'https://imageFromGoogle.com');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```